# Qt source compiled as static

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have compiled the Qt 6.6.0 source `static` as:

```
configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -force-debug-info -skip qtwebengine  -prefix "C:\Qt\6.6.0_static"

cmake --build . --parallel
cmake --install .
cmake --install . --config Debug
```

After modifying anything I'm calling `ninja`

```
C:\Qt\6.6.0_static>ninja
[25/25] Linking CXX executable qtbase\bin\qmleasing.exe
```

It detects the modifications and compiles

However, when debugging the application these modifications are ignored.

I'm using VS22, I tested selecting the `qmake.exe` located in these two folders:

[image: 5a54d5b2-1aa0-4539-9c74-c85621255d9b-image.png]

I have compiled another separate build using the same source and parameters on `configure.bat` removing only the `-static` on this build whenever I modify anything and call `ninja` the modifications get recognized correctly.

When it's a static build, after editing something I need to call any other parameter than `ninja`?

Comment: Are you aware of the Qt license implications of static linking?

Comment: @Botje yes, whats going on?

Comment: So you bought a commercial license of Qt?